# smarty get data from $globals

Tags: php, smarty

If have used {debug} to see what data i can access in a page.
Now the stuff i need sit's in {$GLOBALS} like

```
   current_user => Array (17)
      id => 3759
      user_name => bla
      email => bla@bla.com
      group => Array (2)
        id => users
        caption => Users
```

But how to i get the data i need to show on my page? Like the e-mail adress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've only access to the template file, you could assign `$GLOBALS` to a smarty var `$globals` like this:

```
{php}$this->assign('globals', $GLOBALS);{/php}
{$globals.somevar}
```

`$this` refers to the active Smarty object.

A better way to implement this, when having access to the PHP script, would be:

```
<?php
$somevar = 'this is a test';
$tpl = new Smarty;
$tpl->assign('globals', $GLOBALS);
$tpl->display('example.tpl');
?>
```

Template file:

```
{$globals.somevar}
```

Optionally use a filter like:

```
{$globals.somevar|escape:html}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this may work:

{php}

echo $GLOBALS['current_user']['email'];

{/php}

(This is not the best way. You will need to make sure that the data is escaped before output, so you can use htmlentities() or better to assign the data in your code, see: http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/api.assign.php)